# background image is not being displayed despite correct path of the image is given

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

can somebody explain me why this is not working
i tried different possibility like external and internal css but of no use. do suggest something
thank you.

```css
#intro {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url("C:\Users\manas\OneDrive\Desktop\project newbiz\image\intro-bg.png") center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 200px 0 120px 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h2> solutions</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Edit : 
 I also tried this

```css
  background: url("../images/intro-bg.png");
```

When I use the same thing in img tag it works fine.
Why is this happening?

Comment: hmm..  should be set height and width for #intro

Comment: place your image *intro-bg.png* in subfolder like images and try `background-image: url("./images/intro-bg.png")`

Comment: @AmineKOUIS before using the absolute path i used realtive path and that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok… here’s the problem: Your stylesheet has no idea where c:\f.jpg is. You need to use a relative file path. That is, a file path that points to the location of the image RELATIVE to the document requesting it. That is an absolute file path. The only way I can describe this is:

I’m not really certain of the syntax, but you need to jump up a level in the file system or go one deeper, whatever you prefer.

Here’s your photo:

C:\Users\manas\OneDrive\Desktop\project newbiz\image\intro-bg.png

Your stylesheet needs to know to look beyond the css directory it’s in and go looking up in c:\ or ‘down’ in c:\

Try this once you placed the image in correct path:

background-image: url('..\images\intro-bg.png');

Not sure if that’s going to work but that’s how *Nix systems do it. Here’s what our’s looks like:

background-image: url('../images/intro-bg.png');

I hope that helped. Either that or I just confused you more.

An absolute filepath would probably work on a *Nix system and might work on a Windows system if done correctly… I’ve just never tried because there’s no point really.

Comment: before using the absolute path i was using the relative path, here it is : background: url("../image/intro-bg.png");               But that didnt work. The image is on a folder image of the same folder as the css file is

Comment: Which CSS are you using. SASS, LESS, etc.?